# Creating Kubernetes Endpoint in VSTS generates error

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

What setting up a new Kubernetes endpoint and clicking "Verify Connection" the error message:
"The Kubconfig does not contain user field. Please check the kubeconfig. " - is always displayed.

Have tried multiple ways of outputting the config file to no avail. I've also copy and pasted many sample config files from the web and all end up with the same issue. Anyone been successful in creating a new endpoint?

Comment: Coincidentally, I'm just trying the same myself, and getting the same error (hence how I found this SO question). Where's your cluster hosted? I'm trying to connect to a GKE cluster.

Comment: Using Tectonic for our cluster management. I might try another host and see what difference there is in config files.

Comment: Same here. We used a kubeconfig that worked and about two months ago the same file couldn't be used to create new service endpoints anymore. However, the existing service endpoint using that exact same file still worked to push images to the GCP Registry. The problem is simply that VSTS is forbidding to add it even though it would work.

Comment: I had a similar experience and only after comparing an AKS kubeconfig against a terraform/tectonic generated kubeconfig; I noticed the token was not set in the kubelet users section.  Verify works now!  I felt it was strange since before I was able to merge my contexts with other (docker-for-desktop) and run kubectl commands.

Answer (score 1):

This is followed by [TsuyoshiUshio/KubernetesTask issue 35](https://github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/KubernetesTask/issues/35)

> I try to reproduce, however, I can't do it.
>   I'm not sure, however, I can guess it might the mismatch of the version of the cluster/kubectl which you download by the download `task/kubeconfig`.
>   Workaround might be like this:
>
> - kubectl version in your local machine and check the current server/client version
> - specify the same version as the server on the download task. (by default it is 1.5.2)
> - See the log of your release pipeline which is fail, you can see which `kubectl` command has been executed, do the same thing on your local machine with fitting your local pc's environment.
>
> **The point is, before go to the VSTS, download the kubectl by yourself**.
>   Then, put the kubeconfg on the default folder like `~/.kube/config` or set environment variables `KUBECONFIG` to the binary.
>   Then execute kubectl get nodes and make sure if it works.
>
> My kubeconfig is different format with yours. If you use AKS, `az aks install-cli` command and `az aks get-credentials` command.
>   Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough .
>
> **If it works locally, the config file must work on the VSTS task environment**. (or this task or VSTS has a bug)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. However, this issue is before any tasks can be added. This is creating a Service Endpoint in VSTS so I can't even get to the Task phase of the build :-(

Comment: @SteveP OK, this is different then: anything in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on VSTS.

Here is my workaround to get a Service Connection working (in my case to GCloud):

> 1. Switched Authentication to "Service Account"
>
>    2. Run the two commands told by the info icon next to the fields **Token** and **Certificate**:   *"Token to authenticate against Kubernetes.
>         Use the ‘kubectl get serviceaccounts -o yaml’ and ‘kubectl get secret
>         -o yaml’ commands to get the token."*
>
>       `kubectl get secret -o yaml > kubectl-secret.yaml`
>    3. Search inside the the file *kubectl-secret.yaml* the values **ca.crt** and **token**
>    4. Enter the values inside VSTS to the required fields

Comment: I tried this workaround but got this error  - secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot create secrets in the namespace development

Answer (score 0):

The generated config I was using had a duplicate line, removing this corrected the issue for me.

```
users:
- name: cluster_stuff_here
- name: cluster_stuff_here
```