# TFS Kubernetes connection to Ibm cloud private

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-pak-for-data

I want to create ci/cd from TFS-2018 to IBM cloud Private.
from TFS i facing error:
The Kubconfig does not contain user field. Please check the kubeconfig

please let me know kubeconfig configuration

[image]

Comment: Did you look into adding a user field to the kubeconfig, as the error message indicates?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106010/creating-kubernetes-endpoint-in-vsts-generates-error